# DHCPD DDNS issue

Tags: dns, dhcp

Hi I try to implement DDNS on my DHCPD server here you can find my config

```
authoritative;

default-lease-time 151200;
max-lease-time 259200;

log-facility local7;

ddns-update-style interim;

ddns-updates on;

ddns-domainname "ducamps.win";

ddns-rev-domainname "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";

use-host-decl-names on;

allow client-updates;

allow unknown-clients;

include "/etc/dhcp.key";

zone ducamps.win. {

        primary 192.168.1.10;

        key dhcp;

}

zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {

        primary 192.168.1.10;

        key dhcp;

}
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers 192.168.1.1;

        pool {
                range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.140;
        }
}

host zen-pc {
```

but in my dhcpd log I don't see any request on my DNS

```
oct. 25 21:37:27 VMAS-BUILD dhcpd[2531]: Server starting service.
oct. 25 21:37:33 VMAS-BUILD dhcpd[2531]: DHCPRELEASE of 192.168.1.100 from ee:35:20:fc:7b:04 via ens3 (found)
oct. 25 21:37:33 VMAS-BUILD dhcpd[2531]: DHCPDISCOVER from ee:35:20:fc:7b:04 via ens3
oct. 25 21:37:34 VMAS-BUILD dhcpd[2531]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.100 to ee:35:20:fc:7b:04 via ens3
oct. 25 21:37:34 VMAS-BUILD dhcpd[2531]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.53) from ee:35:20:fc:7b:04 via ens3
oct. 25 21:37:34 VMAS-BUILD dhcpd[2531]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.100 to ee:35:20:fc:7b:04 via ens3
```

could you help me if I have done a mistake In my config file?
(my DNS server is a synology DNS)

Answer (score 0):

ok just forgot dot at the end of option:

```
ddns-domainname "ducamps.win.";

ddns-rev-domainname "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.";
```